# ASP.NET "Site can't be reached" on mobile but not pc and laptop

Tags: asp.net, file-upload

I am getting "Site can't be reached" when trying to submit files to my ASP.Net HomeController on Mobile, but when using chrome or OperaGX on laptop or pc both work.

all devices where used on the same network.

What could possibly be the issue, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This could be DNS related.  Could you say a little more about the setup - e.g. is this site behind a domain or an ip, is it public or on a local network?

Comment: Where is your site hosted? Are you on a corporate network with interesting network routing, or is the site hosted publicly? Is the site using an SSL certificate? If so, is the certificate path valid, or is it only installed on the computers? Is the site on a fully qualified domain?

Comment: The site is hosted on Windows Server using IIS10, so it is public at the moment.

Comment: Do you access the site via a fully qualified domain name, or a server name and port? Does the name resolve correctly on the mobile? A tool such as [nslookup](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.sumeet.nslookup) (not mine, but I do use it on Android myself to check exactly this sort of thing) will help to confirm

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.